# C++ Program process two files and not one

Tags: c++, c++11

So, for an assignment I had to read a file and count its line , words , and chars. The issue is that the program I wrote would read two files but not one, the program would view the text file as something that it can not open and is sent to an else statement. I feel that maybe I messed something up, but I find it strange that it can reads two files and not one.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // for file-access
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1){}
    else
    {
        cout << "File anInvalidFileName is not found" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);

    if (infile.is_open() && infile.good())
    {
        string line1 = "";
        int countline1 = 0;
        int charcount1 = 0;
        char space1;
        int countspace1 = 0;
        int empty1 = 0;
        while (getline(infile, line1))
        {
            if (line1.empty())
            {
                empty1++;
            }
            countline1++;
            charcount1 += line1.length() + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < line1.length(); i++)
            {
                if (line1[i] == ' ')
                {
                    countspace1++;
                }
            }
        }
        countspace1 = (countline1 - empty1) + countspace1;
        ifstream infile(argv[2]); //open the file
        if (infile.is_open() && infile.good())
        {
            string line2 = "";
            int countline2 = 0;
            int charcount2 = 0;
            char space2;
            int countspace2 = 0;
            int empty2 = 0;
            while (getline(infile, line2))
            {
                if (line2.empty())
                {
                    empty2++;
                }
                countline2++;
                charcount2 += line2.length() + 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < line2.length(); i++)
                {
                    if (line2[i] == ' ')
                    {
                        countspace2++;
                    }
                }
            }
            countspace2 = (countline2 - empty2) + countspace2;
            int countline = 0;
            int countspace = 0;
            int charcount = 0;
            countline = countline1 + countline2;

            countspace = countspace1 + countspace2;

            charcount = charcount1 + charcount2;
            cout << setw(12) << countline1;
            cout << setw(12) << countspace1;
            cout << setw(12) << charcount1 << " ";
            cout << argv[1] << endl;
            cout << setw(12) << countline2;
            cout << setw(12) << countspace2;
            cout << setw(12) << charcount2 << " ";
            cout << argv[2] << endl;
            cout << setw(12) << countline;
            cout << setw(12) << countspace;
            cout << setw(12) << charcount << " ";
            cout << "totals" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "error" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }
}
```

The error output is something I added just to see where the one file gets sent to when it fails. It does go to the else, because when I run the program it prints out the error. As for input, the prof provided test cases that run automatically when the program is run.
I feel it might be a simple mistake and maybe I miss understood how argv works, but any help would be welcome. If any more information is needed I'll try to add it.

Comment: Please indent the code properly and explain exactly what you are doing when it works and when it doesn't. For example, the arguments you give it. A debugger would also be the first step to use to see what's happening and what arguments you get in. Spaces in filename?

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like your keyboard is broken and its TAB key doesn't work. As a result, the shown code is completely unreadable. Please get your keyboard fixed, and then use the fixed TAB key to logically indent your code, so that it's actually possible to read it and follow what it's doing.

Comment: Proper indentation would make this a lot more readable. Also I'm sure you could make this sample a lot more minimal than it currently is. TIA.

Comment: If using VS press `ctrl` + `k` + `d`.

Comment: To follow up Borgleader's comment: Make your example only count the number of lines.  That will reduce the length enormously.  Also: It's always worth making your "error" strings unique - even if it's just "error 1", "error 2".

Comment: If I understand correctly, you think it's strange that the program misbehaves if you use `argv[2]` when it's only given one file name. It's not clear why this would be strange.

Comment: You're probably expected to write a function that does the computations and call that several times rather than copy-and-paste, by the way.

Comment: By the way, instead of an empty "then" clause in your first `if` statement, negate the condition.  So make the condition "argc <= 1".  I don't know how `argc` can be 0, as the first parameter is the name of your executable.

Comment: I don't understand.  Your program is reading from 2 files because you explicitly tell it to.  This statement: `ifstream infile(argv[2]);` opens the second file.

Comment: I want it to read the two files, but I also want it to read just one. The reason I though it would be able read just one was because of `ifstream infile(argv[1]);` which would read the first file. The thought I had was that if no second file existed then it would  just ignore ` ifstream infile(argv[2]);` since the next if statement would be false.

Comment: was able to fix it.

Comment: Why do you have an empty if statement `if(argv > 1){}else{...}`? It would be much better to simply do `if(argv <= 1){...}`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for any number of files input.

Hope this helpful to you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    int countline = 0;
    int countspace = 0;
    int charcount = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
      ifstream infile(argv[i]); // open the file
      if (infile.is_open() && infile.good()) {
        string line2 = "";
        int countline2 = 0;
        int charcount2 = 0;
        char space2;
        int countspace2 = 0;
        int empty2 = 0;
        while (getline(infile, line2)) {
          if (line2.empty()) {
            empty2++;
          }
          countline2++;
          charcount2 += line2.length() + 1;
          for (int i = 0; i < line2.length(); i++) {
            if (line2[i] == ' ')
              countspace2++;
          }
        }
        countspace2 = (countline2 - empty2) + countspace2;
        countline += countline2;

        countspace += countspace2;

        charcount += charcount2;
        cout << setw(12) << countline2;
        cout << setw(12) << countspace2;
        cout << setw(12) << charcount2 << " ";
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
        cout << setw(12) << countline;
        cout << setw(12) << countspace;
        cout << setw(12) << charcount << " ";
        cout << "totals" << endl;
      }
      infile.close();
    }
  } else {
    cout << "File anInvalidFileName is not found" << endl;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Will you write code for other posters?  *How* does your code resolve the OP's issue?

Comment: This code snippet can read one file as well as any number of files.